# Name of this Font? Body text in the series of books by Time-Life

Tags: fonts, print-design, font-identification, book

I am trying to identify a font from a series of books by Time-Life that has gone out of print. A sample of the particular is given in the image below:

[image]

OCR, image processing and correlation with font databases failed to return anything meaningful. Human expertise appreciated.

**Note:** We can narrow the search space to all typefaces that were designed before July 1990 since that was the year of publication.

**Edit:** There are no PDF versions, or higher resolutions of this font from search results returned by Google, Bing or DuckDuckGo.

**Update:** Have ordered print versions of the book series. Once they arrive (hopefully soon) high resolution images will be uploaded.

### Additional details:

**Author:** Time-Life Books Editors

**Series:** Voyage Through the Universe Series

**Publication:** 1990-07-01

**Publisher:** Time-Life, Incorporated

Comment: you might want to scan sections of that and then use http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ to identify the specimen

Comment: Tried thrice. Manually edited, thresholded and anti-aliased specimens but the results were disappointing. Good suggestion though.

Comment: Could you add the larger-scale images you've tried, please? Anything could be useful.

Comment: Which font are you referring to in the image? The caption font (sans-serif), or the body copy font (serif)?

Comment: @DLev The body font.

Comment: It's very small and difficult to see the details of the body font... I suggest you scan the section you want to identify and upload a bigger version. I don't think it will be possible to help you if you can't provide a better image!

Comment: Probably Rockwell or Clarendon. It is a **Slab Serif** no doubt. If you  can check the colophon, it may actually be listed.

Comment: I was just about to say what @Yorik says: if you have the actual book, look at the colophon. If that fails, add pictures with the text at a larger size, and preferably find places with some of the more distinctive characters that are missing from the sample you give here, like $, &, Q, 4, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t believe I’ve ever seen this particular variant before, but it is very similar to Linotype’s [Egyptienne F™](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/egyptienne-f/) and Bitstream’s [Humanist Slabserif 712](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/humanist-slabserif-712/), which are almost identical (both based on a design by Adrian Frutiger from 1956). Here is a comparison of a line from the book and Egyptienne F™:

[image: Text from book]
[image: Text in Egyptienne]

It’s impossible to tell, due to the small size and the pixelation of the text from the book, whether this is exactly the font used, but I don’t think it is. If you look very closely, you can see that the top-left terminal of the lowercase *a* in Egyptienne has no finial or serif and is more or less flush with the left of the bowl, making its upper counter fairly wide; in the book text, on the other hand, it seems to have a cusp or serif, and the upper counter is definitely narrower than the lower. The book text also seems to have a slightly higher x-height.

They are very close, though, and I can’t find anything closer than Egyptienne on the regular font sites.

Comment: Looks like we were in sync ;-)

Answer (score 1):

When you're trying to identify a font, it's the details and unique characters that matter. Your image provides next to nothing on either point. Nonetheless ...

Looking closer, those fuzzy characters might be ...

### [Linotype Egyptienne F](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/egyptienne-f/)

[image: Linotype Egyptienne F]

<s>From this low-Earth-orbit view, it appears to be a version of **[Century](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/century/)**, probably the ITC version. If you can find a capital 'Q' you can be pretty sure.</s>

Comment: Definitely not Century. It’s a slab, a (variant of a) relatively common one, too, whose name just refuses to come to me right now.

Comment: Not Clarendon, I assume. You're going to have to post a better image.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Wait a second... you're not the OP. How can you possibly say *definitely* from that image?

Comment: It’s quite clear if you zoom in a bit that it’s definitely not Century. Many of the letters are quite a different shape, and especially the lowercase y and the uppercase J make it clear that it’s a slab (or at least a slab-like serif).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet you got me there. I missed that odd `y`. And when I zoom in to the other fuzzy details it's definitely something slabish. This is going to bug me all day.

Comment: I remembered! See my answer.